# Excel Pivot - Group by year and week

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I can group data by YEAR. I can also group it by WEEK. However, I can't seem to group it by YEAR and WEEK.

I used https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1874-excel-pivot-table-group-by-week.html for reference

Can this be done or is the fact a week can be between two years make it not feasible?

Thanks

Comment: you will need to share some sample data, and possibly a look of what you expect to be able to do, in order to get a meaningful answer. but in short Excel can do ANYTHING :)

Comment: It's literally a list of dates that when I put into a pivot, I want to be able to group by Year and Week

Comment: Could you provide a sample about your PivotTable and data source for date Column?

Comment: A simple solution is to use some helper columns.  In one, extract the year from each date.  In the other, extract the week number from each date.  Include both helper columns in the rows window of the pivot table.  To go beyond generic advice, people will need more detail.

Comment: @pee2pee - CTRL+Left-click is typically used to select multiple values; does that not work?